# Getting carousel data back into object

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am creating a dynamic carousel view in my Xamarin app, and so far it works just fine, but...

My carousel contains students and each carousel page is a link to a student info page. I want to be able to set an object with the current selected student for me to grab on all the students subpages (hope this makes sense :-/).

My script is as follow.

StudentModel:

```
public class StudentData
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string course { get; set; }
    public string schoolclass { get; set; }
    public string profileImage { get; set; }
}
```

CarouselPart:

```
ObservableCollection<StudentData> collection = new ObservableCollection<StudentData>();

collection.Add(new StudentData { name = "Soren Hanson", schoolclass = "4. grade", course = "Math" });
collection.Add(new StudentData { name = "Michael Trane", schoolclass = "7. grade", course = "English" });
collection.Add(new StudentData { name = "Tammy Jump", schoolclass = "1. grade", course = "English" });

DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate(() =>
{
    var imageBtn = new Button();
    imageBtn.Image = "Images/default.png";

    imageBtn.Clicked += delegate {

        // ADDING THE CURRENT STUDENT TO MY CURRSTUDENT OBJECT //
        //App.currStudent = collection.......

        var menteeOptions = new MenteeOptions();
        imageBtn.Navigation.PushAsync(menteeOptions);

    }
}

carousel.ItemTemplate = template;
carousel.PositionSelected += pageChanged;
carousel.ItemsSource = collection;
```

Hoping for help with this and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Do you mean you want get the student data when the current carousel page selected? Why don't you bind carousel   `SelectedItem` ?

Answer (score 0):

Well you question was quite confusing at first but I will answer it from what I understood you want to keep the selected student object with you on your subpages:

So you can either use SQLite for it which can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/databases)

Or you can just maintain it as a static system object on your app.xaml.cs and use it

Something like this

**App.Xaml.cs**

```
 public static object YourDataHolder {get; set;}
```

In your clicked event:

```
imageBtn.Clicked += delegate {

    // ADDING THE CURRENT STUDENT TO MY CURRSTUDENT OBJECT //
    App.YourDataHolder = _yourCollection;

    var menteeOptions = new MenteeOptions();
    imageBtn.Navigation.PushAsync(menteeOptions);

}
```

The use it something like this :

```
fooObject=App.YourDataHolder as FooType;
```